# Evaluate $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ ( \sec x + \tan x)^{9/2}}dx $

Tags: integration

> **Problem** : Evaluate $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ ( \sec x +  \tan x)^{9/2}}dx $
>
> **Solution** :   $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ ( \sec x +  \tan x)^{9/2}}dx $
>
> $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ \left(1+ \sin x \over \cos x \right)^ {9/2}}dx $
>
> $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ (\sin {x \over 2} + \cos {x \over 2})^9 \over (\cos^2 {x \over 2} - \sin^2 {x \over 2})^ {9/2}}dx $
>
> $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ \left(\cos {x \over 2} + \sin {x \over 2} \over\cos {x \over 2} - \sin {x \over 2}\right)^ {9/2}}dx $
>
> $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{ \left(1 + \tan {x \over 2} \over 1 - \tan {x \over 2}\right)^ {9/2}}dx $
>
> $ \int \cfrac { \sec^2x}{[tan({ \pi \over 4}+ { x \over 2})]^  {9/2}}dx $

Am I doing right ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130987/evaluate-int-frac-sec2x-secx-tanx5-2-mathrm-dx?rq=1

Comment: thanks.Above link is useful